# To update values in a table based on condition of values from another table

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I have two tables as under:

```
LEAVEENTITLE
Name                           Null     Type       
------------------------------ -------- -----------------------------------
CL_ENTITLED                    NOT NULL NUMBER(2)
APP_NO                                  NUMBER(6)                 
CL_USED                                 NUMBER(2)        
SL_ENTITLED                    NOT NULL NUMBER(2)        
SL_USED                                 NUMBER(2)        
LTA_ENTITLED                   NOT NULL NUMBER(2)        
LTA_USED                                NUMBER(2)        
ECN                            NOT NULL NUMBER(6)        
CL_UNUSED                               NUMBER(2)        
SL_UNUSED                               NUMBER(2)        
LTA_UNSUED                              NUMBER(2)  


LEAVES
Name                           Null     Type        
------------------------------ -------- ------------------------------------ 
APP_NO                         NOT NULL NUMBER(6)        
ECN                            NOT NULL NUMBER(6)        
FROM_DATE                      NOT NULL DATE
TO_DATE                        NOT NULL DATE        
APP_DATE                       NOT NULL DATE        
NO_OF_DAYS                     NOT NULL NUMBER(3)        
LEAVE_TYPE                     NOT NULL VARCHAR2(25)        
STATUS                         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)        
REMARK                                  VARCHAR2(100)
```

I want to update the `*_USED` columns of `LEAVEENTITLE` table based on the `LEAVE_TYPE` value in `LEAVES` table, e.g.:

- If the `LEAVE_TYPE = 'SL'` then I want to update `SL_USED=SL_USED + LEAVES.NO_OF_DAYS`
- If the `LEAVE_TYPE = 'CL'` then I want to update `CL_USED=CL_USED + LEAVES.NO_OF_DAYS`

Comment: What is `app_no`? Applicant number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Not really an answer to the question, but too big for a comment...*

Trying to maintain roll-up data in a parent table is usually not a good idea, as it's prone to error and confusion. For example, in this case you want to add the values from `leaves` to the `_used` values in `leaveentitle`, which suggests that the `_used` values are non-zero, which in turn suggests you intend to run it more than once. But that means you can count the same `leaves` data more than once. If I add data like this:

```
insert into leaveentitle(app_no, ecn, cl_entitled, sl_entitled, lta_entitled)
values (1, 1234, 5, 10, 5);

insert into leaves (app_no, ecn, from_date, to_date, app_date,
    no_of_days, leave_type, status)
values (1, 1234, date '2012-01-01', date '2012-01-02', date '2011-12-15',
    2, 'SL', 'APPROVED');
```

... and then run an update similar to @Szilard Barany's (with `nvl()` and `sum()`) I end up with:

```
select app_no, ecn, sl_entitled, sl_used, sl_unused
from leaveentitle where app_no = 1 and ecn = 1234;

APP_NO    ECN SL_ENTITLED SL_USED SL_UNUSED
------ ------ ----------- ------- ---------
     1   1234          10       2
```

... which looks OK; but then if I add another `leaves` record:

```
insert into leaves (app_no, ecn, from_date, to_date, app_date,
    no_of_days, leave_type, status)
values (1, 1234, date '2012-02-01', date '2012-02-01', date '2012-01-15',
    1, 'SL', 'BOOKED');
```

... and update again I get:

```
select app_no, ecn, sl_entitled, sl_used, sl_unused
from leaveentitle where app_no = 1 and ecn = 1234;

APP_NO    ECN SL_ENTITLED SL_USED SL_UNUSED
------ ------ ----------- ------- ---------
     1   1234          10       5
```

... which is clearly wrong, as I've only used 3 days, not 5. (I have a feeling my company does something like this since my leave balance is rarely accurate). You could recalculate everything on your update, rather than adding to the existing value; or you could try to use triggers to update the totals; or you could try to maintain state so you know which `leaves` records are already included. But the last two options become horrible too, not least when an existing record changes.

A much simpler option is to drop the `_used` and `_unused` columns from `leaveentitle` and generate the values as needed, probably via a view to make life easier for your users, with a query like (guessing the join condition is both `app_no` and `ecn`, but it's not clear from the question):

```
select le.app_no, le.ecn, le.sl_entitled,
    sum(case when l.leave_type = 'SL' then l.no_of_days else 0 end) as sl_used
from leaveentitle le
join leaves l on l.app_no = le.app_no and l.ecn = le.ecn
group by le.app_no, le.ecn, le.sl_entitled;

APP_NO    ECN SL_ENTITLED SL_USED
------ ------ ----------- -------
     1   1234          10       3
```

... or to get all the values form your original parent table:

```
create or replace view leaveview as
select le.app_no, le.ecn,
    le.sl_entitled, ls.sl_used, le.sl_entitled - ls.sl_used as sl_unused,
    le.cl_entitled, ls.cl_used, le.cl_entitled - ls.cl_used as cl_unused,
    le.lta_entitled, ls.lta_used, le.lta_entitled - ls.lta_used as lta_unused
from leaveentitle le
left join (select l.app_no, l.ecn,
        sum(case when l.leave_type = 'SL' then l.no_of_days else 0 end) as sl_used,
        sum(case when l.leave_type = 'CL' then l.no_of_days else 0 end) as cl_used,
        sum(case when l.leave_type = 'LTA' then l.no_of_days else 0 end) as lta_used
    from leaves l
    group by l.app_no, l.ecn
    ) ls on ls.app_no = le.app_no and ls.ecn = le.ecn;

select * from leaveview where app_no = 1 and ecn = 1234;

APP_NO    ECN SL_ENTITLED SL_USED SL_UNUSED CL_ENTITLED CL_USED CL_UNUSED LTA_ENTITLED LTA_USED LTA_UNUSED
------ ------ ----------- ------- --------- ----------- ------- --------- ------------ -------- ----------
     1   1234          10       3         7           5       0         5            5        0          5
```

This also gives you the ability to add extra derived values easily, such as a split based on `status`, by just adding it to the view, rather than having to add another complicated layer of calculation and update somewhere.

Comment: Thanks. I am ultimately going ahead with the view you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `APP_NO` is the join key between the two tables, you can try something like this:

```
UPDATE leaveentitle le
SET    le.sl_used = le.sl_used + (
           SELECT CASE WHEN ls.leave_type = 'SL' THEN ls.no_of_days ELSE 0 END
           FROM   leaves ls
           WHERE  ls.app_no = le.app_no
       )
     , le.cl_used = le.cl_used + (
           SELECT CASE WHEN ls.leave_type = 'CL' THEN ls.no_of_days ELSE 0 END
           FROM   leaves ls
           WHERE  ls.app_no = le.app_no
       );
```

It assumes that `leaves.app_no` is a primary key; so the subqueries are guaranteed to be scalar.

Comment: The `*_used` values are nullable, so you need to `nvl()` the existing value to zero; and I'd assume there can be more than one `leaves` record per entitlement, so you need to `sum()` those?